# Data Class calculations and alternatives

Tags: vb.net, class, oop

I would like to explore your thoughts on the below.
If I have essentually a data class

```
Public Class Package
    Public Property Length as decimal
    Public property Width as decimal
    Public Property Height as decimal
End Class
```

Now I want a calculated property so I could add this to the class in 3 ways.

1. Have the class property calculate the result

```
Public ReadOnly Property Cubic as decimal
Get
    Return Length * Height * Width
End Get
```

2. Use a calculation class to calculate the result

```
Public ReadOnly Property Cubic as decimal
Get
    Dim Calc as new CalculationClass
    return Calc.Cubic(Length, Width, Height)
End Get
```

3. I could also as an alternative have the property dumb and it could be calculated outside the class soon after the class is populated by calling the same calculation class in example 2. But outside the data class.

```
Private LocalCubic as Decimal
Public Property Cubic
Get
   Return LocalCubic
End Get
Set(value as Decimal)
    LocalCubic=value
End Set
End Property
```

Although the example above for the calculated property is simple I would also like to consider it may not be. It could be 200 or more  lines long to do the calculation and maybe encombusing other properties in a larger DataClass.
There could also be hundreds of package classes created as the program runs.

My understanding of using each one is (Please comment if wrong)

1. Everything is contained in the class, readable and easy to work with. Each Package Class has its own copy of the calculation so for a simple calculation no problem. But if I have 500 package classes with the 'calculation' taking say 200 lines. It seems to me that a I am 'wasting' memory buy having 500 copies of the large calculation compared to the other methods.
2. Only one copy of the actual calculation is used as each class refers to the same calculation object. Every other class (500) is using the same code so it is saving on memory. Probably breaks OOP.
3. Has the advantages of 2) Major disadvantage is that if the Length, With or Height properties change in value at some time after creation and calculation then the Cubic property will be wrong.

Are there any other advantages / disadvantages to the above approaches?
Best Practice?
How do other programmers tackle this?

Thanks

Edit
I think I need to be a bit clearer in my questions above to make it more definative;

A) Does example 2) violate the OOP methodology?

B) Does using 2) create a new instance of the CalculationClass within each package class. Or does each Package class created reuse the same Calculation class code?

Comment: This is an interesting topic but, unfortunately, it's the sort of question that doesn't have a definitive answer and questions that require opinions are OT at SO.

Comment: That said, if the calculation is really the same for many types then I'd be looking at inheriting a common base type that does the calculation for all derived types.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that is another way. It falls into the same advantages / disadvantages as 1). I suppose I am less interested in a definitave answer and hence the 'best practice'. Rather more interested technically in confirming if my knowledge regarding the how the class uses the code is correct. Your comment and 1) I would like to confirm that the code is in fact duplicated (using more memory) and that 2) it resuses common code where the calculation code is not duplicated in the data class. Also is it bad practice to do 2) with regards to OOP

Comment: You don't write code thinking about how much memory your code is going to take up. That's silly. It's all machine code in the end anyway. What you should care about is that your high-level code is well-written and that means that using a base class is better because you write the code once, rather than over and over again in each individual class. It's more like your option 2 in that regard.

Comment: I take your point that these days memory space abundant. I come from an era of writing machine code and still use it for PLC devices where memory is / was a big issue. In relation to the question above. A base class would be of no advantage over 2) as there is only the one same class that is created many times (500). I do agree that in situations where I have different classes all using the same calculations a base class would suit nicely.

Comment: I assumed that you were talking about the same calculation. If all the calculations are different then no, a base class wouldn't help. If there are a limited number of different calculations, each used by a subset of the types, then you would still benefit from multiple base classes. It's possible that you might even use a single abstract base class, so that you could group instances of all the type together and still access that calculated property of each.

Comment: *"I come from an era of writing machine code [...] for PLC devices"*. Fair call. Not something I've done so not a consideration I make. In general application development, not a consideration that you need to make either. Your first priority is how the code looks to you, the developer, and only consider how it looks to the machine if you can achieve a significant enough improvement in efficiency to warrant making the code look worse to you.

Comment: This might be a side track but wanted to clarify what is OT? From a quiick google search it suggested 'Off topic' from UD, but i'm not sure if that's right given the context.

Comment: Off Topic was what I assumed it meant also. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 1):

I would just make the volume a property of the Package class assuming the packages are all rectangular. Force the properties to be set in the constructor and calculate the Volume in the constructor.

```
Public Class Package
    Public Property Length As Decimal
    Public Property Width As Decimal
    Public Property Height As Decimal
    Public Property Volume As Decimal

    Public Sub New(Lgth As Decimal, Wdth As Decimal, Hght As Decimal)
        Length = Lgth
        Width = Wdth
        Height = Hght
        Volume = Length * Width * Height
    End Sub

End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sener As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pk As New Package(7, 5, 10)
    MessageBox.Show(pk.Volume.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to make all the properties read-only in that case and that assumes that the values indeed cannot change.

Comment: @Mary, I'm not really looking for a solution on how to solve this. What you hav eprovided seems the most logical. But it has the issue of creating copies of the Cubic code especially if the code is very long. It is  fictitious problem I am just using it to illistrate a point. I have clarified what I am try to say in the comments above to jmcilhinney

Comment: Could the calculation method go in a module?